# Graphic sound equalizer for Ubuntu

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

Is there a graphic sound equalizer for Ubuntu? I want one for Pulseaudio's global system settings.

Comment: You ask for an equalizer, then proceed to install one. What is your question?

Comment: @Gary Answering your own question is encouraged here. Please remove your answer from your question and place it in an answer box. Thank you!

Comment: @a-j Instead of editing the question you should do as ElderGeek says in the previous comment. Edited.

Comment: @ElderGeek It wasn't OP who added the answer by editing, but user _A J_ :)

Comment: @edwin Huh. looked to me like A J had formatted it.

Comment: @ElderGeek My bad, I didn't see that last line :)

Comment: @edvin, sorry i thought he got problem cause when try to install...

Answer (score 0):

You can follow [this unofficial guide](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/03/install-pulseaudio-with-built-in-system.html) to install the Pulseaudio Equalizer for Ubuntu (12.04 or newer). There is no guarantee, but it should work.
Please, write under here if you need more help and don't forget to press the up arrow on the right if the answer is useful.